# What's wrong with the G-Diffuser?

Tags: starfox-64

So I was playing *Starfox 64* the other day, and I noticed something suspicious.  No matter what course of action I take, if this blue bird guy gets shot too much in the first stage, he tells me that something has happened to his **G-Diffuser**, and he has to break off.

***Hmmmmm...***

---

What does this so-called **G-Diffuser** do? If it's such a critical component of the **Arwing** that even slight damage renders the vehicle inoperable, why wasn't I made aware of it before?  Isn't that a liability that the **commander** of the team should probably know about?  And why does this bird guy's **break** so often in this stage, and yet I've **never** had a problem with mine, and neither has **anyone** else in my team, even under heavy fire?  And why can't that annoying little **frog** do anything about it?  Is this so-called "**G-Diffuser**" merely a ruse created by the bird to get his own skin out of a fight?

This has been bothering me for a while now.  There's something **fishy** going on, I think.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the intro to that level has Fox saying "Check your G-Diffusers" and Falco saying "It's fine" or something along those lines, so that answers your **commander** question

Comment: Falco.... that sneaky SOB

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Gravity Diffusion system, or G-Diffusion, is an experimental power system used in starfighters that reduces gravity forces on the pilot and provides a respectable power source for shields and propulsion.

The G-Diffuser system was created by John Tanaka, from the Galactic Federation and F-Zero game. However, due to the temperamental nature of the G-Diffuser, these systems need to be carefully checked and maintained; while easy to fix in flight, they can consume a pilots' full attention, something that kills pilots in a dogfight.

The G-Diffuser is primarily found on both the Star Fox Team's Arwings and the Star Wolf Team's Wolfen.

[Source](http://starfox.wikia.com/wiki/G-Diffusion)

**If his G-Diffuser is broken, not only is he taking all those G's *straight to the face*, but he's running on low power.  So obviously, he's smart to break off from the group.**

Comment: I'm still not sold.  I've never had a problem with mine.